# CS0119 'Process' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a c sharp program that finds a specific program and attaches to that program only, but everytime I keep getting these errors. In the snippet, the code with the "--" it front of it is what Im getting as a error.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            file.Filter = "*.exe |*.exe";
            file.FileName = @"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\version-0bb91d28bcd0467c";
            if(file.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
                roblox = file.FileName;
 --Process p = Process[] Process.GetProcessesByName(roblox);

                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                p.WaitForInputIdle();
                SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
            }
```

> Error: Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0119  'Process' is a type, which is not valid in the given
>   context   Crazed Lua  C:\Users\willd\source\repos\Crazed Lua\Crazed
>   Lua\Form1.cs  42  Active

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            file.Filter = "*.exe |*.exe";
            file.FileName = @"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\version-0bb91d28bcd0467c";
            if(file.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
                roblox = file.FileName;
 --Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName(roblox);

                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                p.WaitForInputIdle();
                SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
            }
```

> Error: Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Diagnostics.Process[]' to 'System.Diagnostics.Process'    Crazed
>   Lua   C:\Users\willd\source\repos\Crazed Lua\Crazed
>   Lua\Form1.cs  42  Active

Comment: don't simply attach link to images, rather post code snippet with specific highlight to problem statement

Comment: Edit your question and add the code as text. Also, try to ask an actual question.

Comment: You didn't even include the error msg in your img. No one can tell what's going on through those wave lines.

Comment: There added everything you asked.

Answer (score 2):

[Process.GetProcessesByName Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates an array of new Process components and associates them with
>   all the process resources on the local computer that share the
>   specified process name.

Simply just do this

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(roblox);
```

or

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(roblox);
```

To iterate over each process just use a `foreach` loop

```
foreach(var p in processes)
{
   // do stuff with the process p here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

> var p = Process.GetProcessesByName(roblox);

Rather than

> Process p = Process[] Process.GetProcessesByName(roblox);